# How can I hide the second administrator account on the MacBook?

Tags: mac, filevault

I'm using multiple user accounts on one MacBook, let's call them "work" and "home," and FileVault is enabled for each. Both with administrator rights. I need to hide one account (home), which I did through the terminal.

However, after restarting the Mac, both accounts are still displayed on the login screen.

What can I do that after a reboot, only the "home" account is visible, and the "home" account is hidden but accessible for login by clicking on the Other..?

[image: Something like that]

I found the guide called 'Turn off FileVault on Mac'. I hope it doesn't ask for the Recovery Key when turning off because I don't remember it. So, can I disable it for this account and it won't be displayed on the login screen?

SOLVED: so, I found a solution to remove one of the users from FileVault using the terminal code:

```
sudo fdesetup remove -user <Username>
```

Comment: How old is the OS running on this Mac?  It looks like Lion.  FileVault is not a user choice in modern versions of macOS, it's a system-level choice.

Comment: OS is Venture 13.4.1.
Model: MacBook Pro 13" (2020).

Both accounts have FileVault and I found that I can turn it off in the system settings. I assumed that I could turn it off for one account and after that, the account will not be displayed on the login screen.

I have been using only one account "work" for a long time with available FileVault. But then I transferred the second account "home" from my old Macbook. It also has FileVault, but if it's turned on, I see both accounts on the login screen after reboot or shutdown, even if I hide the account "home" through the terminal code

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please use the answer section to put up an answer and then check the solved check mark next to the answer.